# .net pos printer roll printing

Tags: .net, printing

I am developing a system for supermarket which will prints pos bill after invoicing using .net.

For the bill printing I am using System.Drawing.Printing in .net.

The issue was when the item list is too long , when it increase the one page limit pos printer only prints the first page and cut paper.

Following is the code sample for printing which I used. Please help me to solve this.

```
Private Sub printInvoice()

     Dim printDocument As New PrintDocument
     Dim printController As New StandardPrintController
     printDocument.PrintController = printController
     AddHandler printDocument.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintDocumnet_Event
     printDocument.Print()

End Sub

Public Sub PrintDocumnet_Event(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim dataFont As Font = New Font("Courier New", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim leftMargin As Integer = 15
        Dim topMargin As Integer = 65


        For Each invoiceRow As DataRow In dtInvoice.Rows
            Dim code As String = invoiceRow("Item_Code").ToString.Trim
            Dim name As String = invoiceRow("Print_Name").ToString.Trim
            Dim price As String = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Double.Parse(invoiceRow("Price"))) + "x"
            Dim qty As String = String.Format("{0:0.###}", Double.Parse(invoiceRow("Qty")))
            Dim amont As String = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Double.Parse(invoiceRow("Amount")))
            Dim discount As String = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Double.Parse(invoiceRow("Discount")))


            e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0,-8}", name), dataFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin)
            topMargin += 15
            e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0,-10} {1,7} {2,5} {3,8}", code, price, qty, amont), dataFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin)
            topMargin += 20
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What POS printer are you referring to? Might it not be easier to ESC codes to control the printer?

Comment: I am using EPSON TM-T81 POS Printer. And it will automatically cut the paper when done the printing. Here issue was printer cut the paper after printing one page. And rest of the pages are not printing.

Comment: First of all I would double check what your page length settings are, since it is a roll you should be able to make it quite long. I couldn't find the TM-181 manual but other Epson printers maxed out at 1289 inches and make sure you use one PrintDocument

Comment: thnx for reply, I used only one document

Comment: @las What page length is the printer set for then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx for all. I found the solution. I had to check the page height according to item list  and add the following when the page exceeds.

```
 e.HasMorePages = True
```